# How to run .ts(typescript) file directly in cucumber step definition

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am looking for a solution instead of running the .ts file directly,I want to run in cucumber stepdefinition file.

I have SendEMail.ts file in below step:

```
Then('Send Email.', async () => {

//Call SendEMail.ts file

    
console.log("Email validation Done  :");

    
})
```

I want to run this file directly.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: can you explain why you need to call the ts file? you should be calling a method or API from inside the code.

Comment: Hi @GaneshC,thank you for your response.Actually i am trying to send an email using Gmail,but unfortunately i am not able to call the method from outside ,so i am tying to run the .ts file instead.My framework is developed with protrcator and typescript.Appreciate your help.